# Sencha touch vs Dojo Mobile vs jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, dojo, sencha-touch

- I've read the Sencha Touch docs. I feel its MVC model is very attractive but it seems to has a long start-up time, especially with external JavaScript (eg:map).
- Although I'm comfortable using jQuery in a web site, I have concerns about the maturity of jQuery Mobile. (I haven't tested it yet)
- I have no idea about Dojo's mobile framework.

Which of these alternatives do you like? Why?

Comment: I don't know about the first 2, but I really love the dojo one. You can give it a try online at http://maqetta.org/

Comment: This article has a lot of helpful comment: http://www.quora.com/Were-deciding-between-jQuery-Mobile-Sencha-Touch-Dojo-Mobile-What-are-the-pros-and-cons-for-each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what exactly are you requirements? Each framework has different several advantages and disadvantages....

Me personally I use Jquery Mobile, which is now at it's first official release. Don't let version numbers fool you, this has been developed 1 year long and actually works pretty good!
The others provide different capabilities:

1. sencha is based on javascript controls - you create the whole layout from within javascript using JSON notation for properties/actions/events
2. jqm allows you to use your "standard" HTML and enhances it "auto-magically". In my opinion this is the closest to HTML you'll ever get
3. Dojo is more about MVC and allows a more structured environment. Haven't used it personally so I can't say too much about it...

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to build an app that can work well with google maps,but it seems Sencha touch did it bad(At least on android).

Comment: here's a [demo](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html) about using GoogleMaps with JQuery-Mobile, hope this helps you further in your decision making!

Comment: @Leon, how to display charts using JQuery mobile? I haven't seen any demo of such charts on JQuery site. With Dojo and Sencha we can draw charts and graphs.

Comment: @Shekhar better post a new question for that, or search the web for immediate answers!